# How do you calculate the determinant of this magic square?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, determinant, magic-square

> Calculate the determinant of this magic square (which is from Albrecht
>   Dürer's *Melancholia*)
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix} 16  &   3  &   2  &  13 \\   5  &  10  &  11  &   8
>   \\   9  &   6  &   7  &  12 \\   4  &  15  &  14  &   1
>   \end{pmatrix}$$

I'm very unsafe about the term "magic square" and I couldn't find much reliable information on the internet either about calculating their determinant.. : /

Wikipedia says: *A magic square is a $n \times n$ square grid (where $n$ is the number of cells on each side) filled with distinct positive integers in the range $1,2,.., n^2$ such that each cell contains a different integer and the sum of the integers in each row, column and diagonal is equal [...].*

All in all, I don't really see a difference between a normal square matrix and a magic square when it comes to calculate their determinants. Am I right?

If this is the case, I would just calculate the determinant of this magic square by using formula of Laplace choosing the first column of the magic square as pivot column. I did it on paper and I get $$\det =0$$

So basically my question is: When I got this magic square, can I consider it as a normal square matrix when it comes to calculating its determinant? Or do you calculate its determinant completely different?

Comment: You are expected to view the magic square as a matrix and compute the determinant normally.  As the linked answer says, some magic squares have determinant zero and some do not.  The problem just told you it was a magic square to tell you where they got the strange configuration of numbers.

Comment: It is as you say : You just consider the square to be a square matrix.